# Bluetooth LE GAP Service and appearance characteristic

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am studying a Bluetooth LE peripheral and I noticed it doesn't include the Appearance characteristic of the GAP service, just the Device Name characteristic.

If the GAP service lacks the Appearance characteristic which is mandatory in the table below, is it still Bluetooth compliance?

the device is Bluetooth LE 4.0

The only I could find in the CORE 4.0 specs is:

[CORE specs 4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poocp.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information on Appearance in [Core Specification Supplement](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421047&_ga=2.131531916.2028233240.1512573204-44265228.1508744261).
Also all the Appearance assigned keys can be found [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/ko-kr/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.appearance.xml).